# How can to call a module from a class?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, module

You see, we are given by our instructor some codes to study and I was planning on using them to create a log in system but I don't know how. I am fairly new to this and I'm eager to learn. I badly need help.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module MySqlManager

    Public Function GetMySqlConnStr() As String
        Dim connStrBuilder As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder

        With connStrBuilder
            .Server = "localhost"
            .UserID = "root"
            .Password = ""
            .Database = "bloodbank"
            .Port = 3306
        End With

        ''Returns the mysql connection string
        Return connStrBuilder.ConnectionString
    End Function


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Use ExecuteNonQuery for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE query. Returns 0 if failed.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="commandText"></param>
    ''' <param name="parameters"></param>
    Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal commandText As String, ByVal ParamArray parameters As MySqlParameter()) As Integer
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(GetMySqlConnStr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(commandText, conn)
                conn.Open()

                cmd.Prepare()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
                End If

                Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Use ExecuteScalar for querying a single value
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="commandText"></param>
    ''' <param name="parameters"></param>
    Public Function ExecuteScalar(commandText As String, ParamArray parameters As MySqlParameter()) As Object
        Using conn As New MySqlConnection(GetMySqlConnStr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(commandText, conn)
                conn.Open()

                cmd.Prepare()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
                End If

                Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Use ExecuteReader when you are making an SQL call that will return a record set from a table.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="commandText"></param>
    ''' <param name="parameters"></param>
    Public Function ExecuteReader(ByVal commandText As String, ByVal ParamArray parameters As MySqlParameter()) As MySqlDataReader
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(GetMySqlConnStr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(commandText, conn)

            conn.Open()

            cmd.Prepare()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
            End If

            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

            Return reader

        End Using

    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class SomClass
Dim stringValue as string = MySqlManager.GetMySqlConnStr()
End Class
```

Difference between `module` and `class` is that you can only have one `instance` of the `module` when you can have multiple `instances of class`.

Comment: **"you can only have one instance of the module."** I would disagree, modules in VB aren't classes and can't be used to instantiate objects. Rather, they're something similar to namespaces, with the difference that namespaces can't contain functions directly. In general a module is a static class...

Comment: You start with "modules in VB aren't classes" and end with "module is a static class".  Module is vb.net version of c# static class.